# how to minus two time period

Tags: c#

I am developing a c#.net app in which I need to subtract two time periods.
I have taken two date objects and subtracted them but it doesn't work.

Comment: Given two `DateTime` objects, do you need to know the `TimeSpan` between them? `date1` - `date2` should give you this.

Comment: Sorry, I answered, but now I'm not so sure what you meant... can you explain better? Maybe a sample of input and output?

Comment: To me it sounds like he wants to subtract one TimeSpan (= period of time) from another so the result would be another TimeSpan.

Answer (score 8):

TimeSpan can be used to measure the differences between 2 DateTimes:

```
DateTime dt1 = ...
DateTime dt2 = ...
TimeSpan diff = dt2 - dt1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) struct.
Also, for DateTime, you have handy procedures such as `AddDays`:

```
DateTime later = mydate.AddDays(1.0);
```

Similarlly, there are `AddHours`, `AddMonths` and even `AddMilliseconds`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_members.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting one DateTime from another returns a Timespan object. which basically tells you how many days/hours/mins/secs/milliseconds/ticks that occured between the 2 DateTimes.